# Is it possible to write a regex that can capture a variety of Name formats

Tags: regex

I'm trying to write an efficient regular expression that will take the following Name inputs and provide the output set forth below.

[image]

I have created a brute force solution that gets there, but its brittle and will likely not handle any thing new. My brute force approach is here: https://regex101.com/r/fSMeu8/1

Here are the input names:

```
Aubrie Green
Brian Joseph Hernandez, Jr.
Calvin H. Borel
Eddid Martin, Sr.
E. M. Murray
JR Smith, Jr.
HW Bond III
```

Comment: Don't use images as text. Everyone, who needs the data as test case, has to transcribe it - what a waste of time! Without knowing the font, it's even possible to confuse Bond III with Kim Yong Ill. Please transcribe at least the Input.

Comment: Obligatory: [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

Comment: [Here is another brute force approach](https://regex101.com/r/AXYs1A/1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work rather well:

```
^([A-Z](?:[a-z]*\.?))(?:\s*([A-Z](?:[a-z]*\.?)))?\s+([A-Z][a-z]+)((?:, (?:J|S)r\.)|\s+[A-Z]+)?$
```

[Online-Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fSMeu8/5)

Breakdown:

- `([A-Z](?:[a-z]*\.?))`: First name: Exactly one upper-case letter, followed by lower-case letters, a dot, or nothing at all
- `\s*`: Optional spaces between first and middle name
- `([A-Z](?:[a-z]*\.?))?`: Middle name: Like first name, but optional
- `\s+`: There must be a space before the last name
- `([A-Z][a-z]+)`: Last name. That one's simple.
- `((?:, (?:J|S)r\.)|\s+[A-Z]+)?`: Suffix: Jr or Sr or space and roman numeral (could be more restricted)

The main point here is that each of the three names contains *exactly* one upper-case letter.

Needless to say, there are still [many, many, *many* names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/) that this regex (or any other regex, for that matter) will fail to match.

Comment: Jean-Paul Gaultier,
Jean-Marie Le Pen,
Jean Jacques de Castelbajac,
Hélène Dujardin : no one works.

Comment: @EttoreRizza And neither for Japanese or Chinese names, names with umlauts, or those weird names that have a ! in them, or any of the other names from the link I posted. But it works for OP's cases, which might be all that matters.

Answer (score 1):

In Bash with sed, I come pretty close, but Bond III doesn't like the game:

```
for s in "Aubrie Green", "Brian Joseph Hernandez, Jr.", "Calvin H. Borel", "Eddid Martin, Sr.", "E. M. Murray", "JR Smith, Jr.", "HW Bond III"
do
   echo $s | sed -r 's/([A-Z][a-z]*)([ .])?( ?[A-Z]+[a-z]*)?.? ([A-Z][a-z]+(, .r\.)?)/(\1)\t(\3)\t(\4)/'
done 

(Aubrie)    ()  (Green),
(Brian) (Joseph)    (Hernandez, Jr.),
(Calvin)    (H) (Borel),
(Eddid) ()  (Martin, Sr.),
(E) ( M)    (Murray),
(J) (R) (Smith, Jr.),
(H) (W) (Bond) III
```

Of course, we shouldn't forget about little Bobby Tables and Malinda O'rm -rf *;